# How to get the no of occurrences of element in xml data in sql server

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008, select, count

In my xml i want to get the number of occurances of an element how can i do this.

for example in the below xml i want the number of times phone element is occuring

```
<Person>
 <Name>abc</Name>
 <Phone>1234</Phone>
 <Phone>9876</Phone>
 <Phone>5678</Phone>
</Person>
```

How can i achieve this ? Can someone help me .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
declare @xml xml='<Person>
 <Name>abc</Name>
 <Phone>1234</Phone>
 <Phone>9876</Phone>
 <Phone>5678</Phone>
</Person>'

select @xml.value('count(//Person/Phone)','int')
```

Answer (score 1):

You use XPATH. This site has a couple of examples of how to single out a specific type of node, by name. http://www.mycodeshare.com/item/1000000009/mssql-xml-query-using-xquery/

Start there and comment if it is not quite clear enough.